# dart.closingLabels issue in vscode

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Im having a problem in my VSCode using flutter/dart about the `dart.closingLabels`. It seems its like a normal text only.

[image]

as you can see the closing labels is in plain text, how can I change the font color and style of it? I tried to look in dart extension settings but I can't find any settings there.

[image]

this is the only setting for `closing labels`

or did I install some extensions that affect the `dart closing labels`?

[image]

How can I solve this one?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved this issue, just try to change your theme in VS Code and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the color in the workspace workbench.colorCustomizations settings for the token **dart.closingLabels**

[image]

Comment: i tried this one...but it gives me this error.. 

https://i.postimg.cc/3wFQF6kk/image.png

Comment: this is the right solution and it works for me, just note that the parent "settings" is not correct.
the right structure is: `{ "workbench.colorCustomizations": { "dart.closingLabels": "#444" } }`

Answer (score 0):

In the VSCode open the Command Palette by pressing Ctrl + Shift + P, and type/select Preferences: Open Settings (JSON). This will open the editor Settings .json file. Set/add new rules for the editor token color customization.

```
   "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "[Default Dark+]": {
          "dart.closingLabels": "#33ff33"
        }
      },
```

Note: Just name your theme instead of "Default Dark +"